# Angular not displaying data (Nodejs,Jade)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

My app file:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRecourse', 'ngRoute']);
 app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
   $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/main.jade', controller: 'mainCtrl '})
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

 });

 angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl,' function($scope){
   $scope.myVar = "Hello Angular";
 });
```

index page connected with layouts and all the scripts needed :

```
 extends ../includes/layout

 block main-content
   section.content
     div(ng-view)
```

layout.jade :

```
 doctype
 html
   head
     base(href='/')
     link(href="/favicon.ico", rel="shortcut icon", type="image/x-icon")
     link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous")
     link(rel="stylesheet", href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
     link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/site.css")
   body(ng-app='app')
     block main-content
     include scripts
```

and here is my server :

```
 app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function(req,res){
   res.render('partials/' + req.params.partialPath);
 });

 app.get('*', function(req,res){
   res.render('index.jade');
 });
```

I tried to add the app script directly to index, but all I get is a white screen on localhost... I'm using Atom, and I have installed all of the packages I mentioned. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.jade add this line to include AngularJS:

```
script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js")
```

You should also consider migrating from Jade to Pug, it is a newer version with more features and fewer bugs.

Comment: Im new and just found this Angular course... i tried your option but nothing happend...

Comment: If you edit the question to provide a link to the course you're following that could really help understand your direction.  No matter what, you need to include the AngularJS libraries for anything to work.